# Using custom data attribute in Struts 2 s:select

Tags: struts2, struts-tags

I'm trying to use custom data attributes of HTML in Struts2 tags 
here is my sample code

```jsp
<s:select list="myList" listKey="myListVal"  listValue="myListDesc"  data-inputs="myListInput" ></s:select>
```

i was expecting something like this for example

```jsp
<select >
     <option value="myListVal1" data-inputs="myListInput1">myListDesc1</option>
     <option value="myListVal2" data-inputs="myListInput2">myListDesc2</option>
     <option value="myListVal3" data-inputs="myListInput3">myListDesc3</option>
</select>
```

instead I'm getting this

```jsp
<select data-inputs="myListInput" >
     <option value="myListVal1" >myListDesc1</option>
     <option value="myListVal2" >myListDesc2</option>
     <option value="myListVal3" >myListDesc3</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to describe data-attribute in struts select tags for Options inside it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you expected that; there's no mechanism to set an attribute in one tag and have S2 figure out where it's supposed to appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the `<s:select>` tag template. Or just use HTML tags with `<s:iterator>`

```
<select name="list">
   <s:iterator value="myList" status="stat">
      <option value="<s:property value="myListVal"/>" data-inputs="myListInput<s:property value="#stat.index"/>"><s:property value="myListDesc"/></option>
   </s:iterator>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>You can't inject custom attributes into a Struts2 UI Tag directly.</s>

According to Dave Newton's comment, you can with Struts2 >= 2.1.x

But still it's not possible to apply them to the `option` elements instead of the `select`, so I'll leave the answer in case you need to extend the original `select` tag to define a custom behaviour (like apply certain attributes to the options).

---

You can `extend` the `<s:select>` Struts2 tag to allow it to manage new kind of attributes...: http://bodez.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/customising-struts2-jsp-tags/
,

or create your own tag directly, but in your case would be overkill: http://joshuajava.wordpress.com/2008/12/27/creating-custom-components-with-struts-2/).

Last but not least, you could even add your custom attributes once the page is rendered, using something like jQuery (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CLNDs/ ); they will be accessible, but not visible in source.

Comment: You can, there's just no magic to make the attribute show up in arbitrary elements.

Comment: Really ? How ? Just writing it plain in the tag ? Gonna try it right now, thanks

Comment: @DaveNewton: I keep getting Javelin9 JSP compilation errors; I'm using Struts 2.0.14 (due to company standards). Maybe the 'verbatim' mode is allowed in more recents versions of Struts2 ?

Comment: It was introduced in 2.1+, I don't recall exactly which version, though.

Comment: Mistery solved, thanks. We should REALLY change this aged standards and go for Struts 2.3 :/